# Epson LX-310 not working after Cumulative Update 2017-11 Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10 Pro x32 and an Epson LX-310 printer that was working. Yesterday, Windows 10 automatically updated with 2017-11 Cumulative Update for Windows 10.

Today, I cannot print. The printer status is on. When I click "Print a test page", it quickly says the test page has been sent but the printer does not print it.

My printer is connected to a USB port. What wrong with my Windows 10?

Comment: i found the solution. I uninstall update KB4048954 (yesterday installed). Maybe windows 10 other version has other KBxxxxxx. But find update that yesterday installed. After that, restart the computer. It success. **I cannot answer this question because it protected and must requires 10 reputation to answer**

Comment: I can verify this problem with EPSON LQ-590, with either USB or LPT and with either Windows 7 and Windows 10. In Windows 7, the update KB4048957 needs to be uninstalled.

Comment: Additional hint: In Windows 10, you can download a tool from KB3073930 which lets you hide the update KB4048954.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must uninstall the Windows Update with one of the following KB entries (depending on your version of Windows 10):

KB4048955 (Windows10 Version 1709)

KB4048954 (Windows 10 Version 1703)

KB4048953 (Windows 10 Version 1607)

KB4048952 (Windows 10 Version 1511)

KB4048956 (Windows 10 Version 1507)

KB4048957 (Windows 7)

KB4048958 (Windows 8 and 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2)

Comment: If the update install again, you must uninstall again. Then, hide the update. Download the tool from [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3073930/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-driver-update-from-reinstalling-in-window) then run **wushowhide.diagcab**. Choose **Hide Update** and choose the KBxxxxxxx above and Next. The update will not install again.

Answer (score 2):

The latest build 16299.98 has been released, which is used for fixing Epson issue, look at kb4051963

Addressed issue that impacted some Epson SIDM (Dot Matrix) and TM (POS) printers, which were failing to print on x86 and x64-based systems.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4051963

Comment: My printer has latest driver. Your solution is not work too

Comment: try to install the latest update KB4055038

Comment: this update covers only Windows 7 & 8. Hoping an update for windows 10 might be released soon.

Comment: @RomcelGeluz my windows 10 get windows update **KB4055254** [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055254/windows-10-update-kb4055254) yesterday

Comment: kb4051963 is used for 1709 version has been released today

Comment: all the computers i am monitoring are properly working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you may try delete the printer,and stop the printer spooler,and go to C:\Windows\System32\spool\ rename the folder,start the spooler back and reinstall.

Comment: I already test your solution. It not work

Comment: have to remove the windows update will work.
go to add or remove program>view windows update n uninstall it.
kb4048953/kb4048954

Comment: Yes. I already got the solution. I write in my comment. I cannot answer because the question is protected and need 10 reputation to answer